# Hiding UINavigationBar and Status Bar issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to hide my NavigationBar and the Status Bar (slide up animation) and I'm running into an issue.

When the status bar is visible, the origin point of every element that is at 0 point  (x: 0) means right underneath the statusbar. However, when the statusbar is hidden, the 0 (x: 0) point updates to accomodate the new space, and 0 (x: 0) means the absolute top of the screen.

When I hide the status bar and rotate into landscape, the view autosizes and everything is shifted to use the status bar's space, and throws off my animation:

```
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
            // Change to fullscreen mode
            // Hide status bar and navigation bar
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                                    withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
                navBar.frame = CGRectMake(navBar.frame.origin.x,
                                          -navBar.frame.size.height-20,
                                          navBar.frame.size.width,
                                          navBar.frame.size.height);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [navBar setHidden:TRUE];
            }];
        } else {
            // Change to regular mode
            // Show status bar and navigation bar

            [navBar setHidden:FALSE];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO
                                                    withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
                navBar.frame = CGRectMake(navBar.frame.origin.x,
                                              0,
                                              navBar.frame.size.width,
                                              navBar.frame.size.height);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Here's what the screen looks like after rotation's relayout: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/hybaygP.png)

Comment: Can you post some images? It's not very clear what's your problem. When you say "throws off my animation", is that the animation of navBar you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the subdivision of the screen into UIView areas a little bit.

When you're in a navigation controller, there are three views:

- Navigation controller's "root" view
- Inside that, the NavigationBar (which of course is a UIView
- Also inside the navigation controller, a "content area" view

So the Nav controller is managing it's own root view. In that it is filling the space with a NavigationBar at the top, and the rest of the area with one big UIView for content.

When you push *your* view controller onto the navigation stack, the Nav controller is adding *your root* view as the content. So your entire "self.view" is completely contained within the Nav controller's "content" view.

And so, of course, when the Nav controller hides the navigation bar... the "content" view expands up to fill the space. And then that view tells *your* view "hey, there's more space than you're using so *your* view also expands up to completely fill the Nav controller's content view.

So your view's "0" point is always the top of your view. That never changes. What is changing is where "the top of your view" is relative to the top edge of the screen.

If you want your content to remain in same spot on screen when navbar is removed, then you're going to have to account for the fact that your "zero" point is now higher than it was when there was a nav bar pushing the content view down.

Comment: Same applies for the iOS status bar: it takes up screen real estate that makes the UIViews below it shorter. When you remove it, the available space for views gets taller. Rotation causes all views to relayout, so that's probably triggering changes that are adapting.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I'm dealing with. Any suggestions on how to manage it? I added a screenshot of what happens on rotate. Maybe disable relayout somehow? I'm not sure how to detect when it's happened, since unless I rotate, it works fine...